# Race condition in android broadcast receivers?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

So I have a slider in my android application. When I move it to the ON position, I send a broadcast two broadcasts to my background application.

The first broadcast on receive creates/deletes a file depending on the key/value pair in the broadcast. 
The second broadcast on receive checks to see if the file exists or not. If it exists, it executes some code. My code for sending the broadcasts is

```
Intent updateFile = new Intent();           
updateFile.setAction("com.example.makefile");   
updateFile.putExtra("enable", create);          
sendBroadcast(updateFile);

Intent startCode = new Intent();            
startMWC.setAction("com.m87.dev.start");    
sendBroadcast(startCode);
```

I was wondering whether it was possible for the second broadcast to be received first? As in, can there be a case where it checks to see whether the file exists or not before the file has been created?

I've thought about moving the second broadcast to the onReceive for the first broadcast but I don't always want it to be executed which is why I have it like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering whether it was possible for the second broadcast to be received first?

Yes, it's possible, because `sendBroadcast` is asynchronous.

Comment: Would it be bad practice to add in a sleep timer before sending the second broadcast? Is there an nicer way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad practice. I'm not sure, but maybe I would implement it as you wrote - with adding the second `sendBroadcast()` to the `onReceive()` of the first `BroadcastReceiver`. If you don't want it to be called each time, you can always write an additional check...

Comment: Yea thanks. I modified it by only having the single broadcast receiver to check whether the Intent carries the extras which are added with the different intents.